# How to fool host scanner that joomla1.5 is actually joomla 2 and up?

Tags: joomla, migrate, bluehost

I got message from Bluehost thah they will shut down my account if I do not migrate joomla 1.5 to joomla 2 or 3. All these sites are secured with Akeeba admin tool, Firewall, administrator's folder redirection and , etc.
Is there any way (tool, script) to fool the host scanner that my joomla installations are joomla 2 or up?
Thank you

Answer (score 0):

No, there isn't any way to fool them. Even if there was, I would not recommend it.

I can see where they are coming from in 1 way. Joomla 1.5 is old and isn't considered that secure. You should start looking at upgrading to Joomla 2.5 or 3.x due to security fixes, new features, more support, bigger variety of extensions, and more.

However I can understand that if your site is extremely big and uses loads of extensions, this process can take a very long time or in some cases it might not really be possible. I know that some companies took the Joomla 1.5 library and have hacked into it so much that upgrading it would take 10 times longer than creating the site from scratch.

If you are not able to upgrade your site any time soon or there is another reason, then I would strongly suggest moving host.

Comment: I understand that, but as you pointed - it is going to be very long and painful process. Which hosts do you have in mind that would not do such a thing?

Comment: what sort of hosting are you looking for? Shared? VPS server? Dedicated server?

Comment: shared. nothing special

Comment: 1and1 are reliable, however personally I don't like their control panel, but then again, it's down to personal preference. GoDaddy have been know to be very reliable and also also very popular. A company that I used to use called [AvenueHost](http://www.avenuehost.com/web-hosting.php) were extremely good. Brilliant support and always kept PHP and MySQL versions up to date.

Comment: Thanks Lodder. I've had very bad experience with godaddy. I guess they are popular because of the nice naked ladies in their commercials. Will check the rest out. Thank you

Answer (score -1):

@ Lodder is correct

it may be they have supporting daemons it is suggested you upgeade it to 1.7.x

please check [Requirements for Joomla](http://www.joomla.org/technical-requirements.html)

Thanks & Good Luck

Comment: Joomla 1.7 is also old. It was a short term release brought out before 2.5